# Java BNST toString

Tags: java, string, testing, return, binary-search-tree

So I'm working on a school project of an implementation a binary search tree. I have to create a toString method that returns all nodes as string. I was able to do it as a void but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to return a String of all the nodes.

Heres my working void toString function.

```
public void toString(TreeNode node)
{

        if (node == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (node.deleted == true) {
            System.out.print("*" + node.key + " ");
        } 
        else {
            System.out.print(result += node.key + " ");
        }

        toString(node.leftChild);
        toString(node.rightChild);

}
```

and so what I'm trying to figure out is how to make it return a String of all the nodes in the tree. I tried the following but it only returns the first node since it can't enter the recursion.

```
public String toString(TreeNode node)
{
    String result="";

        if (node == null) {
            return "";
        }

        if (node.deleted == true) {
            result += "*" + node.key + " ";
        }
        else {
            result += node.key + " ";
        }

        toString(node.leftChild);
        toString(node.rightChild);

        return result;

}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the desired format of the result string? Solution is simple, you only need to handle the result of the nested `toString()` calls.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think I just figured it out. This is what I did and it seems to be working as it should.

```
public String toString(TreeNode node)
{
    String result="";

        if (node == null) {
            return "";
        }

        if (node.deleted == true) {
            result += "*" + node.key + " ";
        }
        else {
            result += node.key + " ";
        }

        result += toString(node.leftChild);
        result += toString(node.rightChild);

        return result;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code may benefit from using a `StringBuilder` explicitly, which avoids the creation of intermediate string instances:

```
public String toString(TreeNode node) {
    return appendTo(node, new StringBuilder()).toString();
}
private static StringBuilder appendTo(TreeNode node, StringBuilder sb) {
    if(node == null) return sb;
    if(node.deleted) sb.append('*');
    return appendTo(node.rightChild,
                        appendTo(node.leftChild, sb.append(node.key).append(' ')));
}
```

But even when using string concatenation, it doesn’t need to be that complicated:

```
public String toString(TreeNode node) {
    if(node == null) return "";
    return (node.deleted? "*": "") + node.key + ' '
      + toString(node.leftChild) + toString(node.rightChild);
}
```

This still creates less intermediate string instances than your original version.